# Robot framework displays : JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unable to find root selector using "[ng-app]"

Tags: angularjs, selenium, robotframework

I am using Robot framework and using SeleniumLibrary and AngularJSLibrary.

I have a login page which is no angular but subsequent pages has angular. When i run my end to end test that is built using robotframework, it lanches the login page however it is doing nothing and failed.

**Error message:**

> `JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Unable to find root selector using "[ng-app]"`.
>   `Please refer to the AngularJS library documentation for more information on how to resolve this error.`

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  "Angular demo".
...             Demo.

Library         SeleniumLibrary
Library         AngularJSLibrary

*** Keywords ***
Click clients and all accounts
    Wait for Angular
    Click Element   binding=::item.title | translate
    Click Element   xpath=//*[@id="clientsMenu"]/li[1]/button

Account page is displayed
    Title Should be     All-Accounts

Search an account
        Input Text      model=vm.searchDetails.searchString     123
```

Comment: Code sample, please. Please take a look at [how to provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Code Sample, Just used keywords, please see the sample that i updated as a part of description.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  I found my root selector by grepping in my Angular src directory.

```
[devel@localhost src]$ grep selector . -r
./app/app.component.ts:  selector: 'app-root',
```

Add an argument to your .robot Library include of AngularJSLibrary:

```
Library     AngularJSLibrary    root_selector=app-root
```

Note the multiple spaces after "AngularJSLibrary".   I hope this helps.